# It is possible change fragment on button click if EditText is not empty?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have `MainActivity` with `FrameLayout` in witch I load fragments.
Lets say that in `MainActivity` there is a `Button` next, that loads the next fragment

```
public void btnNextClick(View view) {
    Fragment currentFragment;
    currentFragment = new F2Fragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, currentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

This part would load next fragment to screen (in this case `f2Fragment`)
Inside first fragment (`f1Fragment`) i have `EditText` field and I need to change the fragment only if there is some input in `EditText`

I try to use `SharedPreferences` and

```
pref=activity.getSharedPreferences("default", 0);
edt = pref.edit();
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();          
   edt.putString("edtText",edtText.getText().toString()).apply();
}
```

Later in `MainActivity` i try to get that and check length

```
public void btnNextClick(View view) {
      pref = this.getSharedPreferences("default",0);
      String edtText = pref.getString("edtText","");
      if(edtText.length()>0){
          Fragment currentFragment;
          currentFragment = new F2Fragment();
          FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch,currentFragment);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();
      }
}
```

This works only first time, if i stay edit blank and press `next` nothing happen, if i insert some text nothing again, if i start app and insert text, press next it work.

And what if i have two edits that i need check?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible, try EditText with addTextChangedListener this will  help you.

Comment: @waheed akhtar thanx for answer i understand, just one more question, if i have two or more edit that i need to check is good method to use addTextChangedListener of every edit. Sorry i am still litle noob with this :)

Comment: Fragment A and Fragment B are part of Activity A and Button is on Activity which loads a next Fragment A ..B..C ... and then you want to know if edit box on Fragment A   had any text changed?

Comment: @UzairMohammad i want to load next fragment if edit box have value, if is  empty , than nothing.

Comment: Simple man , Use a callback which gets hit on textChangelistner and on im,plementation of that callback listener (Obviously in Activity A) load a new fragment, If you want code snippet i can provide ?

Comment: @maja Yes you have to put that on each edittext. There are different ways to get working what you want but i posted related stuff.addTextChangedListener is good thing you must have some knowledge about it.

Comment: @UzairMohammad thanx I undestand i wold try now :)

Comment: @waheedakhtar thanx You to :) now is work ,greate

Comment: @maja i uploaded the basic code structure try that !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ActivityActivityTablet extends Activity implements      FragmentA.OnEditBoxTextLoadNewFragment{
.
.
.
//other Activity methods and your code
.
.

@Override
  public void OnEditBoxTextLoadNewFragment(String textFromFragA) {
//load new fragment//if else will work if you need more than loading the     fragment
  }
}
```

Fragment should be like this:

```
public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment {
private OnEditBoxTextLoadNewFragment mListener;

//other fragment code of yours

 public interface OnEditBoxTextLoadNewFragment{
     public void OnEditBoxTextLoadNewFragment(String edit text);
 }

 EditText text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {


            if (!s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mListener.OnEditBoxTextLoadNewFragment(s);
            } 

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnEditBoxTextLoadNewFragment) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnEditBoxTextLoadNewFragment");
    }
  }
}
```